# Refer to Embedded Images Width in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to create an expression in the padding of an embedded image in SSRS report so that i can centralize the image dynamically , the problem with SSRS report is that you can't centralized the image, you need to set an expression to set it dynamically , i searched and i found this solution :

Left Padding:

=CStr(Round((3-System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CType(Fields!Photo.Value,Byte()))).Height/96)/2,2)) & "in"

But this in case the image is a database parameter, i want to set the same expression in case my image is embedded so i need to refer to image width dynamically in the above expression, can anyone help me in that, how can i refer to image width and height of an embedded image in an an expression instead of writing the width as number ??

Comment: If an image is embedded, you have options to set fit size/ fill /clip .Can you tell us where you are embedding your images into?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't refer to your image control and that's why you can't get width of your image using custom code or expression like in your example. But if you have embedded image than your image is hardcoded into your rdl file, it's not dinamic like in case with data base option. SSRS support only referening to the collection of textboxes (individual or inside tablix, matrix).
So you can simply look which height/width your image has and put it to your expression:

For padding left:

```
=CStr(Round(("Put here width of your image control in inches"-"Put here width of image in pixes"/"Put here you image resolution")/2,2)) & "in"
```

So if you have image control with width 5 inches and image with width 300 pixes and dpi 96px/in you should set:

```
=CStr(Round((5-300/96)/2,2)) & "in"
```

And the same for padding top, but using height instead of width.

It's not perfect, because if you change your image - you should provide changes also for this expression, but you don't have other choise.