# Get size of SSRS image item

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, reporting, reporting-services-2016

In SQL Server Reporting Services 2016, how can I right-justify a municipal logo image loaded from the database into an image item on the report? I plan to use a calculated expression for the image element's `Padding.Left` attribute to position the image. Each client (municipality) has a different (single) image to be shown on their reports, and they should line up with the right-hand margin of the report in each case.

I already have working code to get the size of the loaded image (based on [this](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/nathaneccles/2014/04/15/ssrs-right-and-centre-align-images-in-a-table/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70846988/ssrs-accessing-system-drawing-image-fromstream), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705958/303101)).

**How can I get the width of the image element on the report layout** to complete the calculation? Some solutions say to use a report parameter or a custom property as a workaround, but I really *really* want to get the design size of the actual image element from the report itself (and make it client-proof!)

I've already tried the following:

- The expression: `=ReportItems!LogoImage.Width`, (where `LogoImage` is the name of the image element). It gives the error: `[BC30456] 'Width' is not a member of 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.ReportItem'`.
- Based on [docs for the ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.reportingservices.ondemandreportrendering.reportitem) .NET class for SSRS 2016, I tried a VB function in the report's Code area:

```vbnet
Public Function GetReportItemWidth(ByVal itemName As String) As Integer
    Dim item As ReportItem
    item = ReportItems(itemName)
    Return item.Width
End Function
```

...but that gives an error `[BC30469] Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.`

- When I qualify the member names:

```vbnet
Public Function GetReportItemWidth(ByVal itemName As String) As Integer
    Dim item As Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.ReportItem
    item = Me.Report.Renderer.Report.GetReportItem(itemName)
    Return item.Width
End Function
```

...I get error `[BC30002] Type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.ReportItem' is not defined.`

I'm getting deeper and deeper into Planet DotNet without really knowing what I'm doing, so I decided to ask for help from the community. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Should I add a reference to `Microsoft.ReportingServices.dll`? It's not in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` like all the other .net assemblies, but several versions of it are in a few other locations on my hard drive. So, which one?
- Am I looking at the correct docs, or is there more than one class named `ReportItem`?

Note that this may be similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946038/refer-to-embedded-images-width-in-ssrs), but the single answer there (with one vote) which says it's not possible, is from 2014, and makes no mention of various things I've already tried, so I thought things may have changed since then. Also, I'm happy to upgrade to Reporting Services 2017 or later, as I see that a lot has changed between SSRS 2016 and SSRS 2017-2022. (e.g. some of the the .NET classes mentioned above no longer exist, from 2017 onwards etc.)